# Creating pricing calculator for J2Store

Tags: j2store

I'm creating j2store app for calculating price based on product dimensions.
I'm using `GetPricingCalculators` event to register my custom calculator like that:

```
function onJ2StoreGetPricingCalculators(&$calculators)
{
       require_once dirname(__FILE__). '/customcalculator.php';
       $calculators['custom'] = 'Custom';
}
```

My calculator class looks like that:

```
class CustomCalculator extends JObject
  {
     public function __construct($config = array())
     {
         parent::__construct ( $config );
     }

     function calculate()
     {
         //just testing
         $pricing->calculator = 'custom';
         return $pricing;
     }
 }
```

But then I try to set the calculator for a product it still remains unchanged (Standard). Maybe I'm missing something? What is the correct way of creating and registering pricing calculator?

Comment: I've found the solution to the problem of not changing pricing calculator value. It's because Joomla has a bug in MySQL PDO driver. If someone experiences similar problems, use MySQLi database driver.

Comment: When providing a resolution for any question, please post an answer (not a comment). If you can offer more information about how/why your solution works and why it is an advisable technique, that would benefit future researchers.